# I receive "Couldn't seek!" when I open a tiff file in jTessBoxEditor

Tags: image-processing, ocr, tesseract, text-recognition

I have a problem with jTessBoxEditor. I can generate a box file from a picture, but when I try to open an image for to modify the box file, I received an error "Couldn't seek" from the jTessBoxEditor. I tried this on both linux and windows and I received the same results...

What can I do to open a picture in jTessBoxEditor and modify the file?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Comment: @SamBing Please see my solution

Answer (score 0):

I met the same error message when I'm using a `.png` file though I named it to `.tif`

Hope it helps:)

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this problem, and the solution is quite stupid. Convert your .tif images to .png(simply by renaming them). Then drag your images in and everything should work.

Comment: dragging whole png to Jtesseract doesnt give boxes right ?how did you solve this